# Cleaner way to delete all content on PV when all pods mounting it are deleted

Tags: kubernetes

We have a number of PV backed by directories on our nodes.  These PVs have a retain policy and we usually want to retain the contents for archiving.

However, I'm writing some logic for restarting in a completely clean state, including clearing the content stored on the PV.  Note this is not deleting the PV, only the data on disk in the PV.

Currently the best process I have come up for automating this would be.

- Add a finalizer to the PVC bound to the PV we want to clear, to prevent a different pod binding them while were doing cleanup.
- delete all the pods using the PVC, again to prevent them writing to it.
- run a job that mounts the PVC and runs a delete on the directory
- remove the finalizer so the PVC can be deleted once the job completes
- Restart all the pods again.

This seems like allot of work.  Does kubernetes provide any easier process for this cleanup, like say some default finalize label that would automatically clear the PV?  I feel like I must be making things harder then it needs to be for such a simple task.

Again to make it clear this behavior is only run occasionally, I want the default behavior to be to retain data.  I just want a clean way to clear it out when we want a complete reset.

Comment: Can you explain why you are trying to use the same PV when you are deleting it's contents. If you are okay with a work around you can configure a dynamic PV with recycle as the reclaim policy. for more information go through this [link](https://kubernetes.io/docs/tasks/administer-cluster/change-pv-reclaim-policy/), in this tutorial they have clearly mentioned how to change the reclaim policy.

Comment: @KranthiveerDontineni good idea, but I would prefer to avoid that.  There is another team responsible with setting up and making sure kubernetes is available everywhere our code deploys, they have the requirements to make sure PVs are available with some freedom for what storage container they use to back those PVs, then we just reuse the already existing PVs.  Dynamically recycling PVs would require transferring responsibility for creating PVs to our team and might require more understanding of the underlying hardware then we want to have.

Comment: recycle policy can be used for static PVs as well, by doing so the data available on the static PV will be cleared and the PV will be made available for next claim.

Comment: @KranthiveerDontineni unfortunately recycle is deprecated or I might have considered it :(  That being said ironically by making me confirm recycle was deprecated as I thought you made me realize retain required manual releasing which lead me to discovering there was already a place where we released those PVs I could reuse to simplify some of the potential code.  Not as simple as I would *like*, but I could simply add a finalizer and then do the delete in the existing reclaim logic.  It moves the deletion to a less optimal time then i'd like, but simplifies the code noticeable

Comment: yes @dsollen I knew that recycle policy got deprecated and only older versions support 
 it now but I forgot to mention it here. However, I'm happy that you found a solution. Can you edit your post and provide the answer in it so that it will be helpful to remaining community members.